# Loop a Power BI API call to pull an unknown number of records to avoid rate limit?

Tags: api, powerbi, powerquery

I am attempting to connect to Palo Alto's Cortex XDR to pull events into Power BI for analysis on Mean Time to Resolution, totals per analyst, etc.

I am able to authenticate and pull the last 100 events. According to the documentation, there is no way to pull more than 100 per query.

This is the query being ran.

```
let
    body = "{ ""request_data"": {}}",
    GetJson = Web.Contents("https://api-{company}.xdr.us.paloaltonetworks.com/public_api/v1/incidents/get_incidents/",
        [  
            Headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/json",
                #"x-xdr-auth-id" = "{API ID}",
                #"Authorization" = "{API KEY}"
            ],
            Content = Text.ToBinary(body)
        ]
    ),
    FormatAsJson = Json.Document(GetJson),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(FormatAsJson),
    Value = #"Converted to Table"{0}[Value],
    incidents = Value[incidents],
    Result = Table.FromRecords(incidents)
in
    Result
```

When looking at the documentation, I notice it has a way to query specific ranges of incidents (not exceeding 100) and attempted to plug that in but was not able to pull the designated events.

Is there a way to loop the API pull to ingest all the events without knowing the total (will be ever increasing)?